# any way to populate databse as the first thing when i run spring boot program

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have an application that reads csv files in a folder and then reads those csv files and put them in a databse but I am not able to figure out how to populate database as soon as I run my spring boot program

my FlightService.java

```
package com.package.service;



@Service
public class FlightService{
    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Akhil\\Desktop\\assignmentFour\\CSV");
    static FlightDao flightDao = (FlightDao) AppContextUtil.context.getBean("flightDao");
    
    public void readCSV() {
        File files[] = dir.listFiles();
        ArrayList<String> listofFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File file : files) {
            Airline airline = FlightController.readFile(file);
            flightDao.saveAirline(airline);
        }
        
    }
}
```

FlightController.java

```
package com.package.controller;

public class FlightController {

    public static final SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    
    public static Airline readFile(File file) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        Airline aObj = new Airline();
        aObj.setName(file.getName());
        HashSet<Flight> flight_Set = new HashSet<Flight>();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            line = reader.readLine();
            
            while (line != null) {
                Flight f = manipulateLine(line,aObj);
                line = reader.readLine();
                flight_Set.add(f);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could Not Read the File");
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Could Not Close the File");
                }
            }
        }
        aObj.setFlights(flight_Set); 
        return aObj;
    }

    private static Flight manipulateLine(String line, Airline aObj) {

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");

        String flightNo = st.nextToken();
        String depLoc = st.nextToken();
        String arrLoc = st.nextToken();

        String validTillDate = st.nextToken();
        Date validTill = new Date();
        try {
            validTill = dateformat.parse(validTillDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.print("Date not in appropriate(dd-MM-yyyy) format");
        }

        int flightTime = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        Double flightDuration = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
        int fare = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

        String avail = st.nextToken();
        Boolean seatAvailability;
        if (avail.charAt(0) == 'Y')
            seatAvailability = true;
        else
            seatAvailability = false;

        String flightClass = st.nextToken();

        return new Flight(flightNo, depLoc, arrLoc, fare, validTill,
                flightTime, flightDuration, seatAvailability, flightClass,aObj);
        }
}
```

For url

```
package com.package.controller;


@Controller
public class FlightCont {
    
     @RequestMapping(value ="/flightSearch" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView flightSearch(@Valid @ModelAttribute("flightDetails")FlightDetailsEntered flightDetails,BindingResult result){
            
            ModelAndView modelAndView =new ModelAndView("flightSearch");
            if(result.hasErrors())
            { 
                System.err.println(result);
                return modelAndView ;
            }
            List<Flight> listOfMatchingFlights= flightDetails.getListOfMatchingFlights();
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("flightList");
            modelAndView.addObject("list", listOfMatchingFlights);
            return modelAndView ;
        }

}
```

As I run the program i am getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flightService' defined in file [C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\project\target\classes\com\package\service\FlightService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here any suggestions would be really helpful

Comment: By POPULATE do you mean create the database and all the required tables?

Comment: yes but that's not the issue as database is being created and data get's added too ( i ran test code to find out) but how to do it as soon as i run my program and viisit m homepage

Comment: `(FlightDao) AppContextUtil.context.getBean("flightDao")` is trying to use a bean before it exists.  Use constructor (preferred) or @Autowired dependency injection.  The use of static is attempting to bypass the spring bean lifecycle, and will not work.  See also @PostConstruct to run a method after the app has started.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep file in classpath(src/main/resources) and load the file as mentioned below,

package com.package.service;

@Service
public class FlightService{

```
 public void readCSV() {
    InputStream stream = readerFile("CSV.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //do nothing
    }
}

private InputStream readerFile(String fileName) {
    return getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
}
```

}